# Find values from text file using batch script

Tags: cmd.exe

I want to make a batch file to achieve two values from a text file
The values in text file (default.txt) are

```
submask=255.255.254.0
gateway=10.13.62.1
```

Script:

```
for %%a in ('"%~dp0default.txt"^|find "submask="') do set "%%a=subm"
  echo %subm%
for %%a in ('"%~dp0default.txt"^|find "gateway="') do set "%%a=gate"
  echo %gate%
```

But the script does not work out. Please help.

REVISED

```
for %%a in ('"%~dp0Submask_Gateway.txt"^|find "submask="') do set subm=%%a
  echo %subm%

for %%a in ('"%~dp0Submask_Gateway.txt"^|find "gateway="') do set gate=%%a
  echo %gate%
```

[image]

2nd Revision

```
@echo on
type "%~dp0Submask_Gateway.txt"
for %%a in ('type "%~dp0Submask_Gateway.txt"^|find "submask="') do set subm=%%a
  echo %subm%

for %%a in (type ' "%~dp0Submask_Gateway.txt"^|find "gateway="') do set gate=%%a
  echo %gate%

pause
```

[image]

Final

```
REM Extract Submask IP address
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%a in ('type "ZZ_Submask_Gateway.txt"^| find "submask="') do set "subm=%%a"
echo %subm%

REM Extract Gateway IP address
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%a in ('type "%~dp0ZZ_Submask_Gateway.txt"^| find "gateway="') do set "gate=%%a"
echo %gate%
```

Comment: Can you use Powershell instead of batch ?

Comment: You are not setting `%subm%` and `%gate%`. Try `do set subm=%%a` and `do set gate=%%a` as your `set` is the wrong way around.

Comment: I changed but It did not achieve the IPs. See pictures.

Comment: `"%~dp0Submask_Gateway.txt"` is not a valid command. Tip: `type "%~dp0Submask_Gateway.txt"` is.

Comment: Hi, I changed as suggested but it did not get the values still. See screenshot and the revised code.

Comment: A plain `for` loop iterates over files. You need a `for /f` loop (see `for /?` for the exact syntax). And you need to escape the `|` as `^|`.

Comment: @Stephan, I finally got it done. I posted my final code  as above.  Thanks for all your valuable advices.

Comment: @S.Brottes Just curiosity want to know how powershell script will be ? Can you post your code to study !

Answer (score 0):

An alternative powershell solution could be :

```
gc Gateway_mask.txt | %{ echo $_.Split("=")[1]}
```